# Referencing log4j config file within executable JAR

Tags: java, jar, log4j

I am creating an executable JAR that uses a couple XML config files, one for the application and one for log4j. To reference my app config file, I do this:

```
InputStream config = Util.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/config.xml");
```

This works fine for my app config, but the problem is that I can't configure log4j like this. Here is the code that configures log4j:

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("/config/log4j.xml");
```

This won't work because the XML file is going to be stored within the packaged JAR. How can I configure log4j to use an XML or properties file within the JAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the URL version of the DOMConfigurator.configure method.  The resource will have to be available at/config/log4j.xml.

```
DOMConfigurator.configure(Util.class.getResource("/config/log4j.xml")
```

Comment: Nice, much simpler solution than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
DOMConfigurator.configure(Util.class.getResource("/config/log4j.xml"));
```