# Configuration path of Log4j2

Tags: configuration, log4j2

I am trying to adopt Log4j2 to my project. Since my Java Application is packeted in a JAR file. I don't want "log4j2.xml" configuration packaged inside of JAR file. I am trying to learn how configuration file works from "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html"

But seems there is no clear instruction regarding altering the configuration file path of the Log4j2.

After googling about this topic I found something like "Referencing log4j config file within executable JAR" [Referencing log4j config file within executable JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446722/referencing-log4j-config-file-within-executable-jar), But this solution is not available any more according to "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html" (if I understand it correctly).

So I am wondering if someone have any idea about this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can set the system property to specify the configuration path.
set the

```
"-Dlog4j.configurationFile="D:\learning\blog\20130115\config\LogConfig.xml"
```

in VM arguments. replace

```
"D:\learning\blog\20130115\config\LogConfig.xml"
```

to your configuration path.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the **log4j2.xml** file in resource directory in your project so that the log4j will locate files under class path automatically.

**Loading log4j2.xml file from the customized location-**

1. You can use the **System property/ VM arguments-** Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/path/to/file/log4j2.xml
   This will work for any web application.
2. For some legacy applications, you can create a class for loading **log4j2.xml/ log4j2.properties** from the custom location on the machine like- **D:/property/log4j2.xml**
   Using any of these approach,during application startup, the log4j2.xml file from the src/resources folder will be overridden by the custom location log4j.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using -Dlogging.config=Path_to_your_file